# How to access the properties of a parent's parent when extending a generic class

Tags: c++

I need an array of objects, with each entry having a different template type. To achieve that I have created an abstract class `Base`, with the class `GenericImplementation<T>` extending it and implementing/specializing the virtual methods. The caller stores different instances of those in a `Base[]` array and calls the virtual methods. All works perfectly.

As soon as I create a class `EvenMoreAdvancedGenericImplementation<T>` extending the former, the code inside has no access to the properties of the `Base` class anymore. See the following mockup:

```cpp
class Base
{
public:
    int baseProperty;
    virtual void saySomethingBasedOnType() = 0;
};

template <typename T>
class GenericImplementation : public Base
{
public:
    void saySomethingBasedOnType() override;
    void accessBasePoperty()
    {
        std::cout << baseProperty; // Correctly prints the value of baseProperty
    }
};

template <typename T>
class EvenMoreAdvancedGenericImplementation : public GenericImplementation<T>
{
public:
    void accessBasePropertyForADifferentCause()
    {
        std::cout << baseProperty; // 'baseProperty' was not declared in this scope 
        std::cout << this->baseProperty; // 'baseProperty' was not declared in this scope 
    }
};
```

When extending from a generic class (and forwarding the outer template type) a class seems to only have access to it's parents but no longer to its grandparents. This problem does not occur when fully specifying the base class like this:

```cpp
template <typename T>
class EvenMoreAdvancedGenericImplementation : public GenericImplementation<int>
```

How can I extend a generic class using type `T` without losing access to the properties of ancestors higher up in the tree?

Comment: [I cannot reproduce your compiler error](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dd0b9dbd85e9f7d3).  `std::cout << this->baseProperty;` should work.

Comment: That turned out to answer my question. The example in my post eventually compiled as well, but it turned out that my intellisense was way less intelligent than the compiler and prevented it from compiling at all. Thanks for your time, I'm finally able to continue.